# Are there any disadvantages to fully formatting (as opposed to quickly formatting) a flash drive, other than time?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting

I'm running Windows 7.  [This comment](https://superuser.com/questions/996570/used-space-on-an-empty-formatted-flash-drive?noredirect=1#comment1376515_996570) on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/996570/used-space-on-an-empty-formatted-flash-drive) suggests that a full format could be bad for the device lifetime, but in reasonable, noticeable (not just theoretical) terms, is this true?

In other words, is there any reason *not* to do a full format, except that it will take longer?

Comment: No;  The very next comment even places some doubt in that statement.  A single full format won't decrease the lifespan of a flash storage device.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it.

The main difference here is that a full format will write to every cluster of the section of the drive that gets formatted.

There's been lots of fear about flash memory having a limited amount of writes.  Some research indicates that early predictions were false.  I've witnessed quite a few discussions, but nobody ever claiming that they've actually experienced problems just from writing a lot.  Mels comment (which comes right after the comment you hyperlink to) suggests an ability to writes to each cluster 100,000 times, if not 1,000,000 times.

In theory, if you keep re-formatting in a loop, multiple times every day, maybe you'll drive your device to exhaustion.  But you're asking about reasonable practice.  In practice, most people typically only format a drive once.  Maybe you're a power user who plays around with different operating systems, and you end up formatting a drive 20 times.  That's still 99,980 more times before a single cluster would be written to too many times.  You'll need to do some other activity to have a seriously noticeable impact.

To summarize my conclusion: a full format is not going to be particularly risky behavior.